# Can give currency pattern in yaxis tickLabel in jqplot?

Tags: jqplot

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_ext() {
        this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
            formatString : ''
        };
    }
</script>
```

I want to format the numbers on my axis like this: `100,000,000.00`. How do I do this in jqplot?

Comment: can you please be more descriptive about your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the formatting you need:

```
tickOptions:{formatString:"%'.2f"}
```

' for the english numeration
.2 is the number of digit after the point